# Cloudant: How to perform wildcard searches on text fields

Tags: lucene, wildcard, cloudant, python-cloudant

I have a db in cloudant that looks like this

```
count word

4     a         
1     a boy
1     a boy goes
```

i want to run a query like this

`word: *boy*`

how do i do this in cloudant? i tried the following but it did not work

```
{
  "selector": {
    "word": "*boy*"
  },
  "fields": [

  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "_id": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `$regex`[condition operator](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#selector-syntax).

```
{
 "selector": {
   "word": {
    "$regex": "boy"
   }
 },
 "fields": [
 ],
 "sort": [
  {
   "_id": "asc"
  }
 ]
}
```

From the doc:

> A regular expression pattern to match against the document field. Only matches when the field is a string value and matches the supplied regular expression.

Because regular expressions do not work with indexes you should consider using [Cloudant Search](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/search.html#search) instead of Cloudant Query if your data set is rather large.

Create a design document that defines an index on the `word` document property:

```
{
 "_id": "_design/search_example",
 "indexes": {
   "word": {
    "index": "function(doc){if (doc.word) {index('word', doc.word, {'store': true});}}"
  }
 }
}
```

Run search:

```
GET https://$HOST/$DATABASE/_design/search_example/_search/word?q=word:boy HTTP/1.1
```

The result will include all documents that contain the specified string in the `word` document property. To return the documents use `?q=word:boy&include_docs=true`

Hope this helps!